# How does one access the preferences menu on Mathematica 11.3 on Windows?

Tags: windows, menu, amazon-web-services

I use Mathematica on the Mac OS, and am a novice at the Windows OS. On my Mac, I can open Mathematica, then click on the "Mathematica" menu, then click on "Preferences..." to get to the preferences menu. On the Windows version (on AWS), there is no "Mathematica" menu. It looks like:
[image: windows menu on AWS]

So how does one access the preferences menu from here?

Comment: it is under `Edit` menu?

Comment: Yes, it is at the bottom of the Edit menu. Thanks!

Comment: May I ask how you got _Mathematica_ on the AWS ?

Comment: I work at Amazon.

Comment: There is a company, Nimbus Services, who can put your copy of Mathematica on AWS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Windows `Preferences` is under the `Edit` menu:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can open "Preferences" dialog programmatically with:

```
FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["PreferencesDialog"]]
```

Comment: That is useful to know, thanks!